# Kotlin Moshi Load Json from assets

Tags: json, kotlin, android-assets, moshi

I'm trying to load an assets Json file into my project with moshi. However, i keep getting the following error:

> com.squareup.moshi.JsonEncodingException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at path $

How should I load the following Json into my project?

**json_file.json**

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Show title",
    "Description": "desc",
    "Artwork": "link",
    "URL": "feed url"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Show title",
    "Description": "desc",
    "Artwork": "link",
    "URL": "feed url"
  }
]
```

This is what I did:

**JsonUtil**

```
object JsonUtil {

    fun getAssetPodcasts(context: Context): List<JsonPodcast>? {
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()

        val listType = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, JsonPodcast::class.java)
        val adapter: JsonAdapter<List<JsonPodcast>> = moshi.adapter(listType)

        val file = "json_file.json"

        val myjson = context.assets.open(file).bufferedReader().use{ it.readText()}

        return adapter.fromJson(myjson)
    }

    @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class JsonPodcast(
        val Name: String,
        val Description: String,
        val Artwork: String,
        val URL: String
    )
}
```

**myactivity**

```
getAssetPodcasts(this)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't you think there is a clue in error message?

Comment: I do, but i don't see what i did wrong comparing my code to the [moshi guide](https://github.com/square/moshi#parse-json-arrays). And i have no idea how to proceed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally managed to fix it. For any future people that might find themselves in the same situation, here's what i did:

Although the json looks perfectly fine, there must have been some wrong encoding. I uploaded the json to [jsoneditoronline](https://jsoneditoronline.org/) and then exported it again. Loaded it, and now the code works just fine.

Lastly, other things you could check to debug;

1. Did the asset file open correctly?
2. Are the dependencies correct?
3. Did you add `.add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())` to the moshi object?
4. Is the listType - if applicable - correct?
5. And is the data class correct?

Happy coding (again)!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need KotlinJsonAdapterFactory() if you use generate adapter annotations for data classes.